# Why can't I create a Date from a string including milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, datetime

In javascript you can create a Date object from a string, like

```
var mydate = new Date('2008/05/10 12:08:20');
console.log(mydate); //=> Sat May 10 2008 12:08:20 GMT+0200
```

Now try this using milliseconds in the string

```
var mydate = new Date('2008/05/10 12:08:20:551'); // or '2008/05/10 12:08:20.551'
console.log(mydate); //=> NaN
```

Just out of curiosity: why is this?

EDIT: thanks for your answers, which all offer sufficient explanation. Maybe in some future there will be support for use of milliseconds in date strings. Untill then I cooked up this, which may be of use to somebody:

```
function dateFromStringWithMilliSeconds(datestr){
    var dat = datestr.split(' ')
        ,timepart = dat[1].split(/:|\./)
        ,datestr = dat[0]+' '+timepart.slice(0,3).join(':')
        ,ms = timepart[timepart.length-1] || 0
        ,date;
    date = new Date(datestr);
    date.setMilliseconds(ms);
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[dateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date)**
>
> > String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the parse method ([IETF-compliant RFC 1123 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123)).

This format doesn't seem to accommodate milliseconds in the date... It may be best to just define the date without ms and then call [`setMilliseconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMilliseconds) afterwards.

Comment: That's what I do (call setMilliseconds() afterwards), just curious why a datestring couldn't contain ms. Thanks for the RFC link, I found 'hour =  2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT [":" 2DIGIT]' in it, so there we have it I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the different components you can use this overload to the `Date` constructor:

```
var mydate = new Date(2008,6,10,12,8,20,551);
```

Note 6 for the month, as the months go from 0-11.

If needed you can take the string representation and split it to its component parts and pass those through to this constructor:

```
var datestring = '2008/05/10 12:08:20:551';
var datearray = datestring.split(/\s|:|\//g)
var mydate = new Date(datearray[0], parseInt(datearray[1]) + 1 , datearray[2], datearray[3],datearray[4],datearray[5],datearray[6]);
```

As described in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) document, the string overload should conform to RFC-1123 (which in turn conforms to [RFC-822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822)) which does not support milliseconds.

Comment: May be more tricky than you think, using a datestring. If I split up the datestring (datestring.split(/\s|:|\//g)), I'll end up with an array. The Date constructor doesn't accept that. Date.apply(null,[the array]) doesn't work either, it gives the current datetime.

Comment: @Koolinc - then don't use the array as is and break it down to its components `[the array][0]` for the year etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ecma-st/Ecma-262.pdf) standard, section 15.9.1.15, does indeed specify milliseconds in the date string format. I'm guessing the browser developers just couldn't be bothered to implement it.